# How to import plot_confusion_matrix on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am having error with importing of plot_confusion_matrix on Google Colab.

Here's what have got so far.
"from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix"

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

#plot non-normalized confusion matrix
titles_options = [("Confusion matrix, without normalization", None),
                  ("Normalized confusion matrix", 'true')]
for title, normalize in titles_options:
    disp = plot_confusion_matrix(logistic_regression, X_test, y_test,
                                 display_labels=class_names,
                                 cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                                 normalize=normalize)
    disp.ax_set_title(title)

    print()
    print(title)
    print(disp.confusion_matrix)

    plt.show()
```

This is the error line of code i got

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-a0efa4bc91ac> in <cell line: 8>()
      7                   ("Normalized confusion matrix", 'true')]
      8 for title, normalize in titles_options:
----> 9     disp = plot_confusion_matrix(logistic_regression, X_test, y_test,
     10                                  display_labels=class_names,
     11                                  cmap=plt.cm.Blues,

NameError: name 'plot_confusion_matrix' is not defined
```

I did "from sklearn.metrics import plot_confusion_matrix". Error are still coming up like this "plot_confusion_matrix' is not defined"

Comment: Did you execute the import code block?